# Multithreading Multiprocessing with non serialisable classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, rospy

I have a python class which communicates via a ROS service with a simulation environment. Now I want to communicate with multiple simulations in parallel.

In detail, the environment class has a step function which takes an argument and returns the simulation observations:

```
self.envs = [Environment("AI1"),
             Environment("AI2")]
self.pool = Pool(processes=len(self.envs))

ac = # some actions 
res0 = self.pool.apply_async(self.envs[0].step, ac[0])
res1 = self.pool.apply_async(self.envs[1].step, ac[1])

res_list = []
res_list.extend(res0.get())
res_list.extend(res1.get())
```

Of course, I get now the following error

> cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.instancemethod failed

because a ROSPy service is a member of `Environment`

Is it possible to create the environments in the pool itself?
Or would switching to python threading help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With threads you won't get this issue.

An alternative is to start subprocesses where the subprocess creates the `Environment` and listens on a queue for requests and pushes responses onto a different queue. That way the environment lives in the subprocess.

Comment: While threading did not give me any performance advantage, creating subprocesses did. Thanks a lot!